# NgFor Angular: Enviar parametro de un array dentro de otro array o guardar en localStorage

Tags: angular, angular6

Estoy trabajando con angular 6. Tengo el siguiente formato que recuperó de una API:

```
    {
   "station":[
      {
         "id_station":"191",
         "place":"Fila 9 del cultivo",
         "brand":"xxxx"
      },
      {
         "id_station":"999",
         "place":"Fila 2 del cultivo",
         "brand":"xxxx"
      }
   ],
   "_id":"5cc2e8d425c4b8ba6cb87bc0",
   "timestamp":"2018-09-25T11:26:23.166Z",
   "name":"xxxxxx",
   "fiware_Service":"xxxx",
   "fiware_ServicePath":"/xxxx",
   "usuario":null,
   "id_greenhouse":1
},
{
   "station":[
      {
         "id_station":"457",
         "place":"Fila 9 del cultivo",
         "brand":"xxxxx"
      },
      {
         "id_station":"012080F3",
         "place":"Fila 2 del cultivo",
         "brand":"xxxxx"
      }
   ],
   "_id":"5ce7ea5ec6b02a54c6a393c9",
   "timestamp":"2018-09-25T11:26:23.166Z",
   "name":"xxxx",
   "fiware_Service":"xxx",
   "fiware_ServicePath":"/xxxxx",
   "usuario":null,
   "id_greenhouse":3
}.......
```

estoy recorriendo esto con NgFor y mostrando la información de la siguiente forma:

```
<div class="col-md-4 text-center" *ngFor="let green of greenhouse;  let i = index">
            <a [routerLink]="['/greenhouse', green._id, green.station.id_station]" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
                <img (click)="local(green.id_greenhouse)" src="assets/img/invernadero.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="">
            </a>
            <hr>
            <b>{{green.name}}</b>
            <hr>
        </div>
```

Tengo la duda de como mostrar la información del array station para enviarla de las dos id_station. Hasta ahora solo consigo enviar el _id ya que no esta dentro de otro array.

Como podria hacer esto?

No se si seria mejor una vez que el usuario haga clic sobre la imagen guardar esa información en localStorage.

Un saludo.

**EDIT01**

Hola de nuevo,

he probado pasando el array completo station al hacer click de tal forma:

```
 <img (click)="local(green.station)" src="assets/img/invernadero.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="">
```

y guardarlo así en localstorage

```
public local(station) {
    localStorage.setItem('id_stationss', JSON.stringify(station));


  }
```